# why I can't get a string from getchar()

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, getchar

I want to get a string by calling function `getchar()`, but there is something wrong.   Below is my code

```
int i, j, t;
char a[N], *p = argv[1];
for (i=0; i<5; a[i]=t, i++){
    if ((t = getchar()) == EOF) break;
}
a[i] = 0;
```

Comment: "Something wrong" is a *bad* problem description

Comment: The initial value of `t` gets stored before it is assigned a value. There is no need to stuff this in to the `for` loop; a simple reordering fixes this.

Comment: What happens when you build the code? What happens when you run it? For some specific input, what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: That's a really weird `for` loop. :-(

Comment: What's wrong in that? (except for unused `j`, `*p` and `argv` and undefined `N`)

Comment: What is `N`? I can't see any problem if it is large enough..

Comment: You have undefined behaviour the first time you read from `t`.

Comment: @CoolGuy; I fail to see that. `t = getchar();` is executed before `a[i]=t;`

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen , Oops. I missed that

Answer (score 2):

Your code depends on the value of `N`. So, change your code like

```
#define N 20      //my assumption

int i, t;

char a[N];   // *p = argv[1]; no relevant for this example

for (i=0; i < N-1; i++){  //check here
    if ((t = getchar()) == EOF) break;
    a[i]=t;
}
a[i] = 0;
```

Remeber, array index in `C` is `0` based.

Comment: And then add the 0 terminator to the end of the array.

Comment: I want to know why it don`t stop after i press "Enter". I think that the code depends on eight the value of N or the enter.

Comment: @HuichuangXuanyuan `ENTER`? why it will stop on `ENTER`? the breaking condition is `EOF`, press `CTRL+D` (on linux).